# $\sin(2\pi x[x])$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

**How to show that $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x[x])$ is  continuous on $\mathbb R$?**

Proof:I used the result

$\vert \sin(x)-\sin(y)\vert <\vert x - y\vert $

Replacing  $x\rightarrow x[x]$ and $y\rightarrow y[y]$,we get

$\vert \sin(2\pi x[x])-\sin(2\pi y[y])\vert <2\pi\vert x[x] - y[y]\vert $

I wanted to some how show that  $\vert x[x] - y[y]\vert <\vert x-y\vert$

So,that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta=\epsilon/2 \pi>0$ such that

$\vert x-y\vert <\delta\implies \vert \sin(2\pi x[x])-\sin(2\pi y[y])\vert <\epsilon$

Need amendments in above proof...

Thank you...

Comment: The continuity is clear for all $x\notin \Bbb Z$, so you just have to prove continuity for $x\in \Bbb Z$. There you use the fact that $[x]$ jumps by $1$ and $x$ is integer and $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: @WhatsUp:How to show this using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Comment: Anwar, $\delta$ will necessarily depend on $x$ (in addition to depending on $\epsilon$). The function is not uniformly continuous (judging from your choice of tags you seem to be interested in uniform continuity as well).

Comment: Notation $[x]$ means round to nearest or round down?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:I've already shown that it is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @WhatsUp:Can it be proved using Seuential criteria for continuity?Actually,I'm not getting what you want say,sorry!!

Comment: Well, then you should know that $\delta=\epsilon/(2\pi)$ cannot possibly work. For if it did, the function would be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @gt6989b:$[x]:=$greatest integer less than or equal to x.

Comment: You need something like $$\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2\pi(|x|+2)}.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:Can we choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2\pi (\vert x \vert ^2+\vert y \vert ^2 +2)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $(k,k+1)$, $\sin(2\pi x\lfloor x\rfloor)=\sin(2k\pi x)$ and this function is notoriously continuous.

Then

$$\lim_{x\to k^-}\sin(2\pi x\lfloor x\rfloor)=\lim_{x\to k^-}\sin(2\pi x(k-1))=0,$$

$$\lim_{x\to k^+}\sin(2\pi x\lfloor x\rfloor)=\lim_{x\to k^+}\sin(2\pi xk)=0,$$
and 
$$\sin(2\pi k\lfloor k\rfloor)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note the discontinuities of $x[x]$ only happen at $\left\{\left. a + \frac12\right| a \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$, which has period $1$. The idea is, when you take the sine, you can transform the period to make it exactly $2\pi$, the natural period of the sine function.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you are right :-) but the general idea would not change for either floor or ceiling, just a period shift